# Function not passing value to other Function

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing, return-value

I need Calc_Velocity_Factor to pass the Velocity_Factor to the Calc_Function but also return the Velocity_Factor to the Main().

When run, everything works correctly, except I get a ' NameError: name 'Velocity_Factor' is not defined'

Velocity_Factor is the return value and a parameter, I don't know if I need to change the name and then put it in as a parameter.

```py
def main():
    import math

    ang = input("\nEnter your angle of takeoff:\n");
    velo = input("Enter your velocity:\n");
    secs = input("Enter your seconds of takeoff:\n");

    # Calculations
    Angle = float(ang)
    Velocity = float(velo)
    Seconds = float(secs)

    Radians = Angle * 3.1415926 / 180

    returned_Distance = Calc_Distance(Velocity, Radians, Seconds)
    print("\nYour Distance is:", returned_Distance)

    returned_Velocity_Factor = Calc_VelocityFactor(Velocity, Radians, Seconds)
    print("\nYour Velocity Factor is:", returned_Velocity_Factor)

    returned_Height = Calc_Height(Seconds, Velocity_Factor)
    print("\nYour Height is:", returned_Height)


def Calc_Distance(Velocity, Radians, Seconds):
    import math
    distance = Velocity * math.cos(Radians) * Seconds
    return distance


def Calc_VelocityFactor(Velocity, Radians, Seconds):
    import math
    Velocity_Factor = Velocity * math.sin(Radians) * Seconds
    return Velocity_Factor


def Calc_Height(Seconds, Velocity_Factor):
    import math
    Height = -0.5 * 9.8 * Seconds ** 2 + Velocity_Factor
    return Height


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this

```
returned_Height = Calc_Height(Seconds, Velocity_Factor)
print("\nYour Height is:", returned_Height)
```

To this

```
returned_Height = Calc_Height(Seconds, returned_Velocity_Factor)
print("\nYour Height is:", returned_Height)
```

and the problem should be solved.

Another tip: Make sure to define your import always on the top of the module and not inside every function you call

Answer (score 0):

```
  def main():
    import math

    ang = input("\nEnter your angle of takeoff:\n");
    velo = input("Enter your velocity:\n");
    secs = input("Enter your seconds of takeoff:\n");

    # Calculations
    Angle = float(ang)
    Velocity = float(velo)
    Seconds = float(secs)

    Radians = Angle * 3.1415926 / 180

    returned_Distance = Calc_Distance(Velocity, Radians, Seconds)
    print("\nYour Distance is:", returned_Distance)

    returned_Velocity_Factor = Calc_VelocityFactor(Velocity, Radians, Seconds)
    print("\nYour Velocity Factor is:", returned_Velocity_Factor)

    returned_Height = Calc_Height(Seconds, returned_Velocity_Factor)
    print("\nYour Height is:", returned_Height)


def Calc_Distance(Velocity, Radians, Seconds):
    import math
    distance = Velocity * math.cos(Radians) * Seconds
    return distance


def Calc_VelocityFactor(Velocity, Radians, Seconds):
    import math
    Velocity_Factor = Velocity * math.sin(Radians) * Seconds
    return Velocity_Factor


def Calc_Height(Seconds, Velocity_Factor):
    import math
    Height = -0.5 * 9.8 * Seconds ** 2 + Velocity_Factor
    return Height


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This error occurs because the return value of `Calc_VelocityFactor` is assigned to `returned_Velocity_Factor` in line 20 but you are passing `Velocity_Factor` in line 21 which doesn't exist. Replace `Velocity_Factor` with `returned_Velocity_Factor`.

`returned_Height = Calc_Height(Seconds, returned_Velocity_Factor)`